# How can I get features that satisfy a QgsExpression using PyQGIS?

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, qgis-plugins, expression

I have two fields say "State" and "name" which would be get from the two comboboxes. After which, based on the current text in the combo box, I want to make QgsExpression and feature that satisfies QgsExpression should be get back and for that feature I would do spatial operations. How this could be done using python?

I want something like this:

```
state= current text in state combo 
city=  current text in city combo
feature = "state" and "city"
exp = QgsExpression(feature)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do something like this (steps explained as comments):

```
# Get the layer reference. In this example I'll use the current layer:
layer = iface.activeLayer()

# Build the expression. STATE and CITY are field names;
#  state and city represent the string values from your combo boxes
expr = QgsExpression( "\"STATE\"='{}' AND \"CITY\"='{}'".format( state, city ) )

# Get a featureIterator from an expression.
# Note: In QGIS 3.x you could use directly: it = layer.getFeatures( expr )
it = layer.getFeatures( QgsFeatureRequest( expr ) )

# Get features from the iterator and do something
for feature in it: 
    print feature.id()
```

Comment: The expression works but i would like to know why is AND within quotes? why not expr = QgsExpression( "\"STATE\"='" + state + AND "'\"CITY\"='"+ city +"'" )

Comment: Because AND is part of the QGIS expression, not part of Python. I suggest you to write the expression in QGIS first, then try to recreate it in PyQGIS.

Comment: yeah i tried the same expression both in QGIS and python. That works.

Comment: I think the expression would be better readable using `'"state"=\'{}\' AND "city"=\'{}\''.format(state, city)`

Comment: MOST important is to put "state" and "city" without "

Answer (score 2):

AND does not seem to me to be within quotes or maybe I am reading it wrong
Picture: first line by gcarrillo and second line by Farook

[image: first line by gcarrillo and second line by Farook]